# Using old values in function call using PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update, postgresql-9.1

I have a trigger that reverts a price of a given model to the old price after an update if the new price is too low.  What I want to do is this:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE revertPrice(OLD.price, model)
```

I know I can't use `OLD` outside of the `WHERE` clause, so is there any work around?  I am running Postgres 9.1.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a BEFORE or AFTER trigger for this job.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

When your trigger is invoked, it automatically has access to the variables `OLD` and `NEW`. You do not need to pass them as parameters. See the documentation linked above.

If you use a `BEFORE` trigger you can modify the price before it's written to the table by altering `NEW`, or you can `RAISE EXCEPTION` to abort the transaction.

Comment: I already am using `AFTER`. So I would write the function and return it as a trigger instead of writing a function that simply changed the value back?  Then I could use the `OLD` and `NEW` within the function?